# Proper use of [Import] attribute in MEF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, mef, extensibility

I'm learning MEF and I wanted to create a simple example (application) to see how it works in action. Thus I thought of a simple translator. I created a solution with four projects (DLL files):

Contracts
Web
BingTranslator
GoogleTranslator

**Contracts** contains the `ITranslate` interface. As the name applies, it would only contain contracts (interfaces), thus exporters and importers can use it.

```
public interface ITranslator
{
    string Translate(string text);
}
```

**BingTranslator** and **GoogleTranslator** are both exporters of this contract. They both implement this contract and provide (export) different translation services (one from Bing, another from Google).

```
[Export(typeof(ITranslator))]
public class GoogleTranslator: ITranslator
{
    public string Translate(string text)
    {
        // Here, I would connect to Google translate and do the work.
        return "Translated by Google Translator";
    }
}
```

and the `BingTranslator` is:

```
[Export(typeof(ITranslator))]
public class BingTranslator : ITranslator
{
    public string Translate(string text)
    {
        return "Translated by Bing";
    }
}
```

Now, in my **Web** project, I simply want to get the text from the user, translate it with one of those translators (Bing and Google), and return the result back to the user. Thus in my **Web** application, I'm dependent upon a translator. Therefore, I've created a controller this way:

```
public class GeneralController : Controller
{
    [Import]
    public ITranslator Translator { get; set; }

    public JsonResult Translate(string text)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            source = text,
            translation = Translator.Translate(text)
        });
    }
}
```

and the last piece of the puzzle should be to glue these components (parts) together (to compose the overall song from smaller pieces). So, in `Application_Start` of the **Web** project, I have:

```
        var parts = new AggregateCatalog
            (
                new DirectoryCatalog(Server.MapPath("/parts")), 
                new DirectoryCatalog(Server.MapPath("/bin"))
            );
        var composer = new CompositionContainer(parts);
        composer.ComposeParts();
```

in which `/parts` is the folder where I drop *GoogleTranslator.dll* and *BingTranslator.dll* files (exporters are located in these files), and in the `/bin` folder 
I simply have my *Web.dll* file which contains importer. However, my problem is that, MEF doesn't populate `Translator` property of the `GeneralController` with the required translator. I read almost every question related to MEF on this site, but I couldn't figure out what's wrong with my example. Can anyone please tell me what I've missed here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK what you need to do is (without prescribing for performance, this is just to see it working)

```
public class GeneralController : Controller
{
    [Import]
    public ITranslator Translator { get; set; }

    public JsonResult Translate(string text)
    {
        var container = new CompositionContainer(
        new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, "Plugins")));
        CompositionBatch compositionBatch = new CompositionBatch();
        compositionBatch.AddPart(this);
        Container.Compose(compositionBatch);

        return Json(new
        {
            source = text,
            translation = Translator.Translate(text)
        });
    }
}
```

---

I am no expert in MEF, and to be frank for what I use it for, it does not do much for me since I only use it to load DLLs and then I have an entry point to dependency inject and from then on I use DI containers and not MEF.

MEF is imperative - as far as I have seen. In your case, you need to pro-actively compose what you need to be MEFed, i.e. *your controller*. **So your controller factory need to compose your controller instance.**

Since I rarely use MEFed components in my MVC app, I have a filter for those actions requiring MEF (instead of MEFing all my controllers in my controller facrory):

```
public class InitialisePluginsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        CompositionBatch compositionBatch = new CompositionBatch();
        compositionBatch.AddPart(filterContext.Controller);
        UniversalCompositionContainer.Current.Container.Compose(
            compositionBatch);
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Here `UniversalCompositionContainer.Current.Container` is a singleton container initialised with my directory catalogs.

---

## My personal view on MEF

MEF, while not a DI framework, it does a lot of that. As such, there is a big overlap with DI and **if you already use DI framework, they are bound to collide**.

MEF is powerful in loading DLLs in runtime especially when you have WPF app where you might be loading/unloading plugins and expect everything else to work as it was, adding/removing features.

For a web app, this does not make a lot of sense, since you are really not supposed to drop a DLL in a working web application. Hence, its uses are very limited.

I am going to write a post on plugins in ASP.NET MVC and will update this post with a link.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Aliostad, but frankly I didn't understand what should I do to make `[Import]` work on my `Translator` property.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati OK, I have updated to demonstrate how to use it.

Comment: Well, here is the counterpart for your view - MEF is part of .NET and a pretty good DI framework in itself. THe use of another one is in most cases not justified and just introduces ANOTHER technology without gain (i.e. maintenance value negative). Just finishd an 18 months project ONLY using MEF ;) Worked quite nice.

Comment: @TomTom it might be because I do not MEF very well, as I said in the beginning. Yet, MEF is lacking many features of a proper DI framework. Does it support DI for func and action?

Comment: Well, my car also can not fly. The question is not whether you can come up with a list of fancy features that it does not support, but whether it is good enough. I ONLY add additional technologies when there is a significant benefit. MEF is part of .NET - so it is there. Anything else... The questin is not "can MEF do this and that" but "is this and that worth adding another item to the technology stack".

Comment: @TomTom func injection is not fancy, at least for me. My code is heavily functional. Also MEF dependency injection requires you to proactively compose objects while DI, it happens all in the background and I do not have to write code for it. I use MEF but only for loading assemblies.

Answer (score 5):

MEF will only populate imports on the objects which it constructs itself. In the case of ASP.NET MVC, it is ASP.NET which creates the controller objects. It will not recognize the `[Import]` attribute, so that's why you see that the dependency is missing.

To make MEF construct the controllers, you have to do the following:

1. Mark the controller class itself with `[Export]`.
2. Implement a [IDependencyResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.idependencyresolver%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) implementation which wraps the MEF container. You can implement [GetService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.idependencyresolver.getservice%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) by asking the MEF container for a matching export. You can generate a MEF contract string from the requested type with `AttributedModelServices.GetContractName`.
3. Register that resolver by calling [DependencyResolver.SetResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416564%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) in `Application_Start`.

You probably also need to mark most of your exported parts with `[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]` to prevent the same instance from being reused in several requests concurrently. Any state kept in your MEF parts would be subject to race conditions otherwise.

**edit**: this [blog post](http://www.bryanavery.co.uk/post/2012/03/12/Using-MEF-in-MVC-3.aspx) has a good example of the whole procedure.

**edit2**: there may be another problem. The MEF container will hold references to any `IDisposable` object it creates, so that it can dispose those objects when the container itself is disposed. However, this is not appropriate for objects with a "per request" lifetime! You will effectively have a memory leak for any services which implement `IDisposable`.

It is probably easier to just use an alternative like [AutoFac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/), which has a NuGet package for [ASP.NET MVC integration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Mvc3Integration) and which has support for [per-request lifetimes](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/InstanceScope).

Comment: +1. MEF was not designed as a DI Framework, hence using it for DI is so complicated - well originally developed for VS plugins. All DI framework support service location by passing the type instance.

Comment: @Aliostad: It turns out that this isn't really a problem because MEF contracts are actually strings which you can generate yourself from the type. I'll update my answer.

Comment: MEF is great, but it's truly silly to add non-semantic attributes to a type which provides no services at all. I mean, what if my controller doesn't provide (export) any service? Should I always decorate it with `[Export]` attribute? If so, I prefer to use another approach.

Comment: @Neamati: a Controller handles HTTP requests, that's the *service* it provides.

Answer (score 3):

As @Aliostad mentioned, you do need to have the composition initialise code running during/after controller creation for it to work - simply having it in the global.asax file will not work.

However, you will also need to use `[ImportMany]` instead of just `[Import]`, since in your example you could be working with any number of ITranslator implementations from the binaries that you discover. The point being that if you have many `ITranslator`, but are importing them into a single instance, you will likely get an exception from MEF since it won't know which implementation you actually want.

So instead you use:

```
[ImportMany]
public IEnumerable<ITranslator> Translator { get; set; }
```

Quick example:

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/very-basic-mef-sample-using-importmany.html